# How do I position an element relative to another without taking up space

Tags: html, css

I'd like to show a popup, when clicked, underneath the clicked element.
This element however is positioned between other elements.
When I place the popup between 2 other elements and make it position relative, it still takes up space.

In below simplified example I'd like to position the 'menu' underneath the div with the value 'X'.

```css
.icon {
  font-size: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
  padding-top: 2px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.v-divider {
  float: left;
  height: 35px;
  border: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #d9d6d0;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
  padding: 5px;
}

.block {
  float: left;
  margin: 7px 0px 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class='v-divider'></div>
<div class='block'>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
</div>
<div class='v-divider'></div>
<div class='block'>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
</div>
<div class='v-divider'></div>

<div class='menu'>
  <div id='menu'>
    <span>blabla</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='block'>
  <button type="button" class="icon">X</button>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
</div>
<div class='v-divider'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the snippet, do you want the same.

```js
$( ".icon" ).click(function() {
var offset = $(this).position();
console.log( "left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
$(".menu").css({"left":offset.left});
});
```

```css
.icon {
  font-size: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
  padding-top: 2px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.v-divider {
  float: left;
  height: 35px;
  border: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #d9d6d0;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.block {
  float: left;
  margin: 7px 0px 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='v-divider'></div>
<div class='block'>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
</div>
<div class='v-divider'></div>
<div class='block'>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
</div>
<div class='v-divider'></div>

<div class='menu'>
  <div id='menu'>
    <span>blabla</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='block'>
  <button type="button" class="icon">X</button>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
</div>
<div class='v-divider'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#1").click(function(event){
        $("#popup").toggleClass("none");
    }); 
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#popup {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  top:30px;
}

.none{
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropbtn, .icon {
  font-size: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 32px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
  padding-top: 2px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.v-divider {
  float: left;
  height: 35px;
  border: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #d9d6d0;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}
.block {
  float: left;
  margin: 7px 0px 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='v-divider'></div>
<div class='block'>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
</div>
<div class='v-divider'></div>
<div class='block'>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
</div>
<div class='v-divider'></div>

<div class='block'>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" id="1">X</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content none" id="popup">
      <a href="#">blabla</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="icon">A</button>
</div>
<div class='v-divider'></div>
```

Maybe this could work, I used the code on
[W3SCHOOLS DROPDOWN MENU](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp)

That is done with hovers, if you want to check it out, is pretty useful. For my example, I used the names of their clases, and basically the popup has a z-index, this places the content inside it above or below some other content, and using the position absolute, the popup being relative to the .dropdown class, the top value moves it from it's parent, and not from the page, so it won't be jumping around.

The next thing was using jQuery to check on the click event on the button with an x, that has the id='1', each time that the button is clicked, it will toggle the class none in the popup, changing it's display property.