# Positioning dynamically relative to parent without taking up original space

Tags: html, css

My problem is similar to this post: [How do I position an element relative to another without taking up space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292956/how-do-i-position-an-element-relative-to-another-without-taking-up-space).

Though what I want is not exactly what was proposed there. But until now it was the closest example which I could find.

From what I understand, in this example, the position of the element in question gets updated only when a click on an icon-element is detected.

But with *position:fixed* that would mean that a scrolling wouldn't change the position.

What I want is to move the relatively positioned element dynamically with its parents while it does not take up its original space. (Background: I want some submenu-item-div to appear above its parent.) So the structure is similar to this:

```
<div class="entry-options">
    <div class="menu1"></div> 
    <div class="menu2">
        <div class="submenu2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

submenu2 should be positioned above the entry-options (a horizontal bar) without changing its height or width, which should only be determined by the menu* - items.

Is that possible without changing the structure?

Comment: can you put a more complete code and be more precise .. maybe you can add a screenshot to show us what you need

Comment: use `position: absolute`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add `position: relative;` to the parent and `position: absolute` to the child, the child will be positioned relative to the parent without taking up original space.

Comment: Wow; that was so fast that I can't accept the answer yet! Worked like a charm, you saved me a lot of time AND I learned something. So thank you very much; I will accept this when I am allowed to in around 10 minutes :)